# Java generics on Double, Long

Tags: java, generics

```
double izracun = visina / (double)gorDol * sirina / (double)levoDesno;

T smallestVolume;
if (smallestVolume == (long)smallestVolume) {
    smallestVolume = (Long)Math.round(izracun);
} else {
    smallestVolume = (Double)izracun;
}
```

I'm checking first to see if a number is 1.35 or 1.00 and if it is 1.00 I want it to print out 1. Now I want to do this using generics. The above doesn't work of course.

Comment: "Now I want to do this using generics" I don't think you quite understand what generics can be used for. The best you can do here is `Number smallestVolume;`; generics aren't required.

Comment: do you familiar with `.equals` method ?

Comment: Oh didn't know about Number... Anyway even if generics aren't meant for that, how would you do it? Anyway going to use Number.

Comment: "how would you do it" Using `Number`; that's why I suggested it.

Comment: There is really honestly no good way of doing this.  Give up and stick to a specific concrete numeric type.

Comment: Weird I have never seen it, but ye it does the job.